# Is there a clickable state for a StateListDrawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-drawable

I'm building a custom view that can optionally be clickable. I'd like to set a background that indicates the clickable state. Usually, I would do this with an [XML Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) implemented something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_white_grey_spinner_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_white_grey_spinner_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's an `android:state_clickable` or `android:state_pressable` attribute. This seems like a weird oversight considering there's an `android:state_long_pressable`. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is done in the layout: `android:clickable="true|false"`. Not in the drawable itself. For reference:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable

Comment: @Funkystein: Yes, I'll set whether the view is clickable in the layout, but I want to indicate whether the view is clickable using the background.

Comment: You could use the `state_enabled` to set a different bg color when it is enabled or disabled. Where enabled means clickable, **indirectly**.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like there is one. Perhaps they figured `state_enabled` would already convey that. You could certainly implement a custom state yourself, though; it's relatively simple. [This (off-site) page](https://charlesharley.com/2012/programming/custom-drawable-states-in-android) has a nice, straightforward example. Incidentally, that `state_long_pressable` you mention is kind of a custom one itself, in that it's not one of the core system states, but one created separately for the long-since deprecated `KeyboardView`.

Answer (score 4):

State "enabled" itself is used when we want to set any drawable to the view when its clickable. So "state_enabled" is used to convey a particular view is clickable.

But we can also create a custom drawable state for a particular view and use it to define stateListDrawable

Please check the steps below to create custom drawable state for a view:

1. Create attrs.xml in res/values and add below code in it:

   ```
   <resources>
       <declare-styleable name="food">
           <attr name="state_clickable" format="boolean" />
       </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Create a Custom View which will honour custom drawable state. Adding a sample custom view class below.
   We will have to override `onCreateDrawableState` method and merge the existing drawable state with the new one.

   ```
    class CustomButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
    ) : MaterialButton(context, attrs) {

    private val STATE_CLICKABLE = intArrayOf(R.attr.state_clickable)


    override fun onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace: Int): IntArray {
        val drawableStates: IntArray = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1)
        if (this.isClickable) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableStates, STATE_CLICKABLE);
            }
            return drawableStates
        }
    }
   ```
3. Now we can make use of state_clickable in the stateListDrawable. Refer below:

Create a stateListDrawable in res/drawables/button_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/yourAppPackage">
<item
    app:state_clickable="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/item_clickable" />
<item
    app:state_clickable="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/item_non_clickable" />
</selector>
```

This drawable can now be used as background for custom view

Answer (score 2):

You should combine states for single item:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_white_grey_spinner_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/background_white_grey_spinner_normal" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
```